# Is product of two decreasing functions (and positive) decreasing as well?

Tags: functions, monotone-functions

I have two functions $f(x)>0$ and $g(x)>0$, both decreasing. Then, can I claim that the product $f(x)g(x)$ is decreasing as well? ($x>0$)

Comment: That is obvious, by the very definition of‘decreasing’.

Comment: Yes since they are positive functions

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, $0<a<b$ and $0<c<d$ implies $ac <bc <bd$ so $ac <bd$.

Let $x<y$ and take $a=f(x), b=f(y), c=g(x), d=f(y)$.

Comment: Thanks. Does this claim work for two increasing functions as well?  I mean, is the product of two increasing (and positive) functions, increasing?

Comment: Yes, it surely does. @katy98

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy i think you meant d = g(y), right?

Answer (score 2):

Assume $y>x$. We have $f(x)\geq f(y)$, and since $g(x)>0$ it follows that $f(x)g(x)\geq f(y)g(x)$. Also, we have $g(x)\geq g(y)$ and since $f(y)>0$ we get $g(x)f(y)\geq g(y)f(y)$. Combining this together we indeed get $f(x)g(x)\geq f(y)g(y)$.